# METEOR, NGINX subpath error

Tags: javascript, meteor, nginx

i have an app deployed with nginx and docker, now i added a second one also with docker so, this will be the case

DOCKER_METEOR_APP1

DOCKER_METEOR_APP2

Both are in the same server SERVER_IP

http://SERVER_IP/DOCKER_METEOR_APP1

http://SERVER_IP/DOCKER_METEOR_APP2

***MY NGINX Config is this:***

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

# HTTP
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name MY_COOL_SERVER;

    location /DOCKER_METEOR_APP1 {
        proxy_pass http://SERVER_IP:8001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        if ($uri != '/') {
            expires 30d;
        }
    }

    location /DOCKER_METEOR_APP2 {
        proxy_pass http://SERVER_IP:8002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        if ($uri != '/') {
            expires 30d;
        }
    }

}
```

**THE PROBLEM ?**

Each time i try to access one or other app i get the page title and error... it seems that is trying to load content from the root path like

http://SERVER_IP.com/hjas867651877e1u9812931.css?...

What im doing wrong ? is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey... my solution to this issue

- Added ROOT_URL to each app on

`ENV ROOT_URL http://127.0.0.1/DOCKER_METEOR_APP1`

- Also, on `lib/startup.js`

`Meteor.startup(function() {
      process.env.ROOT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1/DOCKER_METEOR_APP1/';
    });`

- And... on my react router got this:

`const history = useBasename( createHistory )(
         { basename: '/DOCKER_METEOR_APP1' }
    )`

`<Router history={history}>`